# AMP story page with form inside

Tags: amp-html, amp-story

How to make valid AMP story page with simply form inside?
I switched `amp-form` component and tried to add form by some different ways but all of them are recognized as invalid cause

> The tag 'form' may not appear as a descendant of tag 'xxx'.

Comment: Did the error message actually says tag 'xxx'?

Comment: @user2468968 , amp-story-grid-layer, amp-story-cta-layer for example.

Comment: Great! The error message is accurate. These tags are not allowed in amp-story.

Comment: The error message does not help me to resolve this task as your clarification too

Answer (score 1):

<amp-form> as of this writing is not a valid child of <amp-story-grid-layer>. See

```
https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-story#children-(of-amp-story)
```

For simple push-button actions, you can consider using <amp-story-cta-layer>

Comment: I get it. I need to add a full form, not simply a button.

Comment: The practical solution would be to provide a link to a form on a separate page or present your story not using <amp-story>. A form in <amp-story> could adversely affect its "defined navigation" in my opinion (hence the provision for <amp-cta-layer>).

Comment: @Mik I'm not aware of any workarounds to get around what you are requesting, but if you provide more information on what type of experience you are trying to create, maybe there is a way you can create it without requiring use of a `<form>`

Comment: @JonNewmuis , I should have made Whatsapp Click to Chat form with one text input and one button. Now I have made just generic link (button) and customer found it's acceptable.